# How can I do about " and ' for saved object in server side and use it for JSON.parse() in javascript?

Tags: grails

How can I do about " and ' for saving object and use it for JSON.parse() in javascript?

Because I have some strings and user can type using `"` and `'` in a single string, for example `"some description like "abc" for '3 feet"` or `"about 3'5 feet"` or `"wel"come""`. When I want to transform into a JSON, especially when I want to parse in view side, for example:

```
var test = '${test as JSON}';
```

It breaks because contains escape like `\"`

However, if only contains `"` and use this `JSON.parse("[{"abc": "asda"das"}]")`, still invalid, because need escape.

So, I really don't know what I should do in thoses cases. I need some explanation how to fix, avoid or magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON can be treated directly as `Object` in Javascript. So you can simply write:

```
var test = ${(test as JSON).toString()}
```

Optionally, you can pass `true` to the `toString()` method to make the JSON pretty string or Object.

```
var test = ${(test as JSON).toString(true)}
```